# Best visual representation for monthly values

Tags: info-visualisation

What kind of data visualizations do you use to show a binary state of a month?

By "binary" i mean just two options for a month. Either "available" or "not available". The last vis on the example image would display that. But is this really the best solution available?

Examples could be:

- Best Travel Season
- Hunting Season

See image for examples on (non-binary) visualization. What do you think about a "classical" visualization like this: http://www.weather2travel.com/whentotravel/spain/costa-blanca/

[image]

What are your experiences with the usability of those kind of images?
Thanks

Comment: Could you clarify what kind of binary data you mean, as any given month could feasibly have more than two 'best time' for X activity. Is the bottom visualisation not already binary? in that it only shows two states per section of the month.

Comment: thx for the hint, updated a bit clarification. Yes the last visualization would realize "binary as on OR off" but is this the best solution? (not very pretty also)

Answer (score 2):

If this is just a list of months representing different state (true|false or on|off) I would use a valid icon for the different modes like the ones below. I'd also make the off|false modes looking disabled (a less intense color, as in greyed out which is something you see often in applications). Disabled because it's there but inaccessible.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ft6nG3.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

... but if this was a continous process, such as months with nice traveling weather, I'd try something looking more like a period of time rather than distinct months. Such as this:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOsBTU.png)</sup>

The point here is that you don't have to write out all months of the year since they are continous. You get from the picture that January - August have the same state and that September - December also have the same state. Again I use the disabled grey style for Off season.

If users get confused by this, shown in a usability test, you could always add the in-between-months later on.

Answer (score 0):

An idea is colour schemes. They have been proven to get their message across better because they stand out (and look pretty). If you are using binary values then I would say do something similar to what [Benny Skogberg has proposed](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/34173/3865) but with colour. Then comes the decision, Red for no and Green for yes? Red for hot and Light blue for cold? Just find a combination that fits with what you're trying to portray. Also bare in mind that even though some colour schemes are known by everyone as standards it's always handy to have a legend to reinforce what they mean.

Comment: Colour is not enough. Think of colour-blind people. Put different patterns too.